# python3 unicode "\\u7ea2" display correctly

Tags: python, unicode-string

when I crawl a website data

```
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36", 
       "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
req = requests.get("http://my089.p2peye.com/shuju?&type=new_borrow_paid&flag=2", headers = headers)
```

the req.text is a string contains these chars:

```
\\u7ea2\\u5cad\\u521b\\u6295
```

but what I want is a string like this:

```
\u7ea2\u5cad\u521b\u6295
```

how could remove "\" before "\u7ea2" so that the unicode string displays in my screen correctly?

Comment: How are you actually crawling?

Comment: just using requests library, and getting an ajax request. the string is contained in response.text

Comment: Do include the `response.text` in the question, along how you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you get from the server is encoded as [JSON](http://json.org/). That's where the double backslashes come from.

You need to decode the JSON to get the data structure it represents.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}

response = requests.get("http://my089.p2peye.com/shuju?&type=new_borrow_paid&flag=2", headers = headers)

data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data['message'])    
# >>> '数据查询成功'
```